# Typescript ignoring if statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a problem with a Next.JS React-Typescript app

I have a code as follows for controlling the video HTML element

```
const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>();
useEffect(() => {
     videoRef !== undefined ? videoRef.current.play() : null;
}, []);
```

Normally everything works fine, but when I try to build the app, the command line says "Object may be undefined", referring to videoRef. Please help.

Comment: have you tried safe navigation operator? Like this `videoRef?.current?.play()`

Comment: try adding  // @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.  before the if condition in the useEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current can be undefined until the component is mounted. UseEffect is triggered after the first render. You should do it like this

```
...
const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>();
useEffect(() => {
     videoRef.current?.play();
}, []);
...
```

I don't see component return but you should also get this error
`Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLVideoElement | null'.ts(2322)`
on ref attr in video tag.

Because Ref type is defined like this in TS

```
 type Ref<T> = RefCallback<T> | RefObject<T> | null;
 type LegacyRef<T> = string | Ref<T>;
```

Your videRef should be set to `null` initially. It should look like this in the end.

```
...
const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
useEffect(() => {
     videoRef.current?.play();
}, []);
...
```

same thing with if statement syntax

```
...
const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
useEffect(() => {
    if(videoRef.current) {
      videoRef.current.play();
    }
  }, []);
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked successfully 

Comment: np. I am glad it did :)